# Changing to the same css path shows different result

Tags: css

This html:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
    #outter_div .span_class a {background: red;}
    #inner_div span a {background: blue;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id='outter_div'>
<div id='inner_div'>
    <span id='span_id' class='span_class'><a href='index.html'>link</a></span>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

results in RED link.

And if we change first line of css to

```
#span_id a {background: red;}
```

Link becomes BLUE.

But both `#outter_div .span_class a` and `#span_id a` point to the same element.

Where does this difference come from? Why does a color change when everything is the same?

Comment: I am trying to fix this - http://unraveled.com/publications/assets/css_tabs/index.html , so that selected tab is defined by tab id, not by body id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you know how to mathematically calculate the specific weight of your CSS selectors ?

Read this.

[how to mathematically calculate the specific weight of your CSS selectors](http://www.webteacher.ws/2008/05/19/tip-calculate-the-specificity-of-css-selectors/)

So back to your question.

```
#span_id a {background: red;}
```

1, 0, 1

```
#inner_div span a {background: blue;}
```

1, 0, 2

Therefore, the link is blue.

It was red before because

```
#outter_div .span_class a {background: red;}
```

1, 1, 1

Answer (score 1):

The difference comes from something called [CSS Specificity](http://css-tricks.com/855-specifics-on-css-specificity/).

It's a concept that allows you to logically order CSS rules in priority based on the number of specific types of selectors you use - ID selectors have the most specificity, and element selectors have the least.

For example, the two selectors selecting an HTML tag `<h1 id="one" class="one">...</h1>`:

```
#one{
    color: red;
}
.one{
    color: blue;
}
h1{
    color: green;
}
```

Will appear **red**. Removing the `#one` selector will now make it appear **blue**, and finally, removing the `.one` selector will make it appear **green**.